Edit line items on front-end once order is placed
When I post an order, in the line items I give it a few custom option with it like palletAmount, palletCost, queueOrder, ... Once the order is placed, how do I edit these in the front-end again?
I have a form that is controlled by a module. But when I submit the changes I get a "405 Method Not Allowed Post request required".
Can someone help me with this. Help would be much appreciated.
This is my code:
front-end
              <form method="post" action="{{ url('order/update-line-item-options') }}">
              {{ csrfInput() }}
              <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="{{ order.id }}">
               {% for lineItem in order.lineItems %}
                  <input type="hidden" name="lineItemId" value="{{ lineItem.id }}">
                  <label for="palletAmount">Pallet Amount</label>
                  <input type="number" name="options[palletAmount]" value="{{ lineItem.options.palletAmount }}">

                  <label for="palletCost">Pallet Cost</label>
                  <input type="number" name="options[palletCost]" value="{{ lineItem.options.palletCost }}">

                  <label for="orderQueue">Order Queue</label>
                  <input type="number" name="options[queueOrder]" value="{{ lineItem.options.queueOrder }}">
               {% endfor %}
              <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
          </form>

modules>orderedit>OrderEdit.php
 <?php
namespace modules\orderedit;

use Craft;
use craft\commerce\Plugin as Commerce;
use yii\base\Module;
use craft\web\Controller;
use craft\web\UrlManager;
use yii\base\Event;

class OrderEdit extends Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Set the controller namespace to this module's namespace
        $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\orderedit\controllers';

        // Register the module with Craft CMS
        Craft::$app->setModule('orderedit', $this);

        // Register custom routes
        Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
            function (Event $event) {
                $event->rules['order/update-line-item-options'] = 'orderedit/order/update-line-item-options';
            }
        );

        // Optionally, register CP routes
        Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
            function (Event $event) {
                $event->rules['cp/orderedit'] = 'orderedit/order/index';
            }
        );
    }
}

modules > orderedit > controllers > OrderController.php
<?php

namespace modules\orderedit\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\commerce\Plugin as Commerce;
use craft\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpdateLineItemOptions(): Response
    {
        $this->requirePostRequest();

        $orderId = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('orderId');
        $lineItemId = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('lineItemId');
        $options = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('options');

        $order = Commerce::getInstance()->orders->getOrderById($orderId);

        if ($order) {
            // Find the line item by ID
            $lineItem = null;
            foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->id == $lineItemId) {
                    $lineItem = $item;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($lineItem) {
                $lineItem->setOptions($options);
                Commerce::getInstance()->lineItems->saveLineItem($lineItem);
            }
        }

        // Optionally redirect or return a success response
        return $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
    }
}


It looks like you are putting your form action in the form tag. Craft requires that the action is a param and craft provides a helper function in twig for it:
<form method="post" action="">
{{ actionInput('module/controller/action' }}
{{ csrfInput() }}


Absolute legend!! Was breaking my head around it. Thanks
